# Which model is the fastest using linq, foreign key relationships or local lists?

Tags: c#, linq, foreign-keys, database-performance

Some basics

I have two tables, one holding the users and one holding a log with logins.
The user table holds something like 15000+ users, the login table is growing and is reaching 150000+ posts.
The database is built upon SQL Server (not express).

To administer the users I got a gridview (ASPxGridView from Devexpress) that I populate from an ObjectDatasource.

Is there any general do’s and donts I should know about when summarizing the number of logins a user made.

Things are getting strangely slow.

Here is a picture showing the involved tables.
[image]

I’ve tried a few things.

```
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();

// Using foregin key relationship
foreach (var proUser in db.tblPROUsers)
{
    var count = proUser.tblPROUserLogins.Count;
    //...
}
```

**Execution time: 01:29.316 (1 minute and 29 seconds)**

```
// By storing a list in a local variable (I removed the FK relation)
var userLogins = db.tblPROUserLogins.ToList();
foreach (var proUser in db.tblPROUsers)
{
    var count = userLogins.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(proUser.UserId)).Count();
    //...
}
```

**Execution time: 01:18.410 (1 minute and 18 seconds)**

```
// By storing a dictionary in a local variable (I removed the FK relation)
var userLogins = db.tblPROUserLogins.ToDictionary(x => x.UserLoginId, x => x.UserId);
foreach (var proUser in db.tblPROUsers)
{
    var count = userLogins.Where(x => x.Value.Equals(proUser.UserId)).Count();
    //...
}
```

**Execution time: 01:15.821 (1 minute and 15 seconds)**

The model giving the best performance is actually the dictionary. However I you know of any options I'd like to hear about it, also if there's something "bad" with this kind of coding when handling such large amounts of data.

Thanks

========================================================

UPDATED With a model according to BrokenGlass example

```
// By storing a dictionary in a local variable (I removed the FK relation)
foreach (var proUser in db.tblPROUsers)
{
    var userId = proUser.UserId;
    var count = db.tblPROUserLogins.Count(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId));
    //...
}
```

**Execution time: 02:01.135 (2 minutes and 1 second)**

In addition to this I created a list storing a simple class

```
public class LoginCount
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And in the summarizing method

```
var loginCount = new List<LoginCount>();

// This foreach loop takes approx 30 secs
foreach (var login in db.tblPROUserLogins)
{
    var userId = login.UserId;

    // Check if available
    var existing = loginCount.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (existing != null)
        existing.Count++;
    else
        loginCount.Add(new LoginCount{UserId = userId, Count = 1});
}

// Calling it
foreach (var proUser in tblProUser)
{
    var user = proUser;
    var userId = user.UserId;

    // Count logins
    var count = 0;
    var loginCounter = loginCount.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(loginCounter != null)
        count = loginCounter.Count;
    //...
}
```

**Execution time: 00:36.841 (36 seconds)**

Conclusion so far, summarizing with linq is slow, but Im getting there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it would be useful if you tried to construct an SQL query that does the same thing and executing it independently of your application (in SQL Server Management Studio). Something like:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserLoginId)
FROM tblPROUserLogin
GROUP BY UserId
```

*(NOTE: This just selects `UserId`. If you want other fields from `tblPROUser`, you'll need a simple JOIN "on top" of this basic query.)*

Ensure there is a **composite index on {UserId, UserLoginId}** and it is being used by the query plan. Having both fields in the index and in that order ensures your query can run without touching the `tblPROUserLogin` table:

[image]

Then benchmark and see if you can get a significantly better time than your LINQ code:

- If yes, then you'll need to find a way to "coax" the LINQ to generate a similar query.
- If no, then you are already as fast as you'll ever be.

**--- EDIT ---**

The follwing LINQ snippet is equivalent to the query above:

```
var db = new UserLoginDataContext();

db.Log = Console.Out;

var result =
    from user_login in db.tblPROUserLogins
    group user_login by user_login.UserId into g
    select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

foreach (var row in result) {
    int user_id = row.UserId;
    int count = row.Count;
    // ...
}
```

Which prints the following text in the console:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], [t0].[UserId]
FROM [dbo].[tblPROUserLogin] AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].[UserId]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

To have the "whole" user and not just `UserId`, you can do this:

```
var db = new UserLoginDataContext();

db.Log = Console.Out;

var login_counts =
    from user_login in db.tblPROUserLogins
    group user_login by user_login.UserId into g
    select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var result =
    from user in db.tblPROUsers
    join login_count in login_counts on user.UserId equals login_count.UserId
    select new { User = user, Count = login_count.Count };

foreach (var row in result) {
    tblPROUser user = row.User;
    int count = row.Count;
    // ...
}
```

And the console output shows the following query...

```
SELECT [t0].[UserId], [t0].[UserGuid], [t0].[CompanyId], [t0].[UserName], [t0].[UserPassword], [t2].[value] AS [Count]
FROM [dbo].[tblPROUser] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t1].[UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblPROUserLogin] AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[UserId]
    ) AS [t2] ON [t0].[UserId] = [t2].[UserId]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

...which should be very efficient provided your indexes are correct:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close to what I did, I will benchmark this later!

Comment: @Trikks When you do the benchmark, could you please let us know of results? I'm curious how much improvement will this approach yield on your data.

Answer (score 1):

The second case *should* always be the fastest by far provided you drop the `ToList()` so counting can be done on the database side, not in memory:

```
var userId = proUser.UserId;
var count = db.tblPROUserLogins.Count(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

Also you have to put the user id into a "plain" primitive variable first since EF can't deal with mapping properties of an object.

Comment: I actually seem to loose performance using this model, I've updated the examples a bit. Declaring the user id as a primitive variable helped a bit though, cutting of like 25% of the execution times! Thanks

Comment: @Trikks: This doesn't make any sense, this should be very fast.  the equivalent SQL is `select count(*) from tblPROUSERLogins where UserLoginId = 'Foo'`

Comment: Also I didn't see you show the timing for this. Only thing needed should be these two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, doing this blind since I'm not on my normal computer.  Just a couple of questions

- do you have an index on the user id in the logins table
- have you tried a view specifically crafted for this page?
- are you using paging to get the users, or trying to get all counts at once?
- have you run sql profiler and watched the actual sql being sent?

Does something like this work for you?

```
var allOfIt = from c in db.tblProUsers 
        select new {
             User  = c, 
             Count = db.tblProUserLogins.Count(l => l.UserId == c.UserId)
        }
        .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
        .Take(pageSize) // page size
```